# changing the title of subviews of headerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frameWidth, 24.0)];
    [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, self.view.frameWidth - 100, header.frameHeight)];
    label.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];

    [header addSubview:label];
    if (section == kEditInformationSection){
        label.text = [AHConstants kEditInformation];

        UIButton *editInformationButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frameWidth - 50, 0, 50, header.frameHeight)];
        [editInformationButton setTag:1000];
        [editInformationButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [editInformationButton setTitle:[AHConstants kEdit] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editInformationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToEditMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.editInformationButton_ = editInformationButton;
        [header addSubview:self.editInformationButton_];
        self.tableHeaderView_ = header;
        return self.tableHeaderView_;
    } else if (section == kNotificationIntervalInfo){
         label.text = [AHConstants kNotificationInterval];
        return header;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

and on the button action, I wanted to change the button title so I did the following:

```
[self.editInformationButton_ setTitle:[AHConstants kDone] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What is AHConstants kDone?

Comment: try to Reload the tableview on the switchToEditMode: method..

Comment: It's got to be something simple because this works fine for me. I'd try `NSLog(@"%p", self.editInformationButton_)` in the `viewForHeaderInSection` and then again right before try changing the title, and make sure you're getting the same address (i.e. you're dealing with the same button, the instance variable didn't get reset at some point, etc.). You can use that to confirm that the table wasn't reloaded (i.e. that `viewForHeaderInSection` was called again in the interim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation`

```
//provide your index for section here
[[self yourTableView]reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Just `handle` these method with `new title`:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```